# Django Crispy forms not showing bootstrap/css or button

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I got crispy forms working with my model, though the form looks plain and bootstrap not showing up, also there seems to be no button. Even when adding button and clicking it(it refreshes)  no data has been saved to the database. I have tried many ways. What seems to be wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated.

forms.py

```
   class PlotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_tag = False
    helper.form_method = 'POST'

    class Meta:
        model = Plot
        fields = '__all__'
```

views:

```
def plot_form(request):
    return render(request, 'plot_form.html', {'form': PlotForm()})
```

the html:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
   {% crispy form %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="save">
```

Comment: does that solves your problem ?

Comment: no, it did not @Bhansa

Answer (score 1):

First the `{% csrf_token %}` is missing. Second If I remember it correct you need to use `{{ form|crispy }}` to load the form.

And third I would recommend to use [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)

```
<form method='POST' action="/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 {% load widget_tweaks %}
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.first_name |add_class:"customCSS1 customCSS2" }}
 {{ form.second_name |add_class:"customCSS3 customCSS4" }}
</form>
{{ form.media.js }}
```

with this plugin you can style the form as you wish. All Css classes work. Crispy is nice but you have get into the documentation and there are always some workarounds you need to do when you want to style the form. With Widget Tweaks you can simply apply any CSS class. When you really know your way around with crispy you can do a lot but to get to that point....
I switched at some Point and now everything works like a charm

Hope that helps if not leave a comment :)

> Edit

I just saw something in your views.py. You are not referencing the form correct as far as I can tell.

```
from appName.forms import PlotForm

def plot_form(request):
  form = PlotForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) #request files is only required when you want to upload a file
  if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit = False)
    ...
    instance.save()
    #messages.success(request, 'form was saved') #optional
  context = {
  'form':form,
  }
  return render(request, 'AppName/plot_form.html', context)
```

Maybe that will do the trick. You did not have a form validation and Im not sure if the "()" at `{'form': PlotForm()}` would break the code.

Comment: As far as i remember, crispy form handles the crsf token hence we dont need to use it. I am using the template tag not crispy filter. Thanks for the information but i was looking for a way to use only crispy forms to achieve it. :/

Comment: @Achilles ok I just edited something, maybe this will help. Anyway good luck I hope you will make it work with crispy.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Solved it by testing it on firefox instead of google chrome. Apparently, Chrome does not load CSS style for a few local web apps. Got it to work after following this hack. https://css-tricks.com/new-in-chrome-css-overview/